# changing a working url to a new one and getting 404 error

Tags: html, url, path, http-status-code-404

I'm kinda new with all the web apps.
I have a source code that i've got from others and the usualy url i used to login was:

http://www.ctdm.org:8080/WebCT/login.html?pin=10

which is work just fine, although in the server the only file "login.html" is inside "WebCT/WebContent/login.html". do you know why is it like that? Also, if i added to the url the extra folder (which is the true path) it doesn't work (error 404)- i.e.

http://www.ctdm.org:8080/WebCT/WebContent/login.html?pin=10

now, i added more pages so i want now that the user will enter to the page "WebCT/WebContent/index.html"
but again. i get 404 error. I think it's the same problem of the login.html file.

do you know what's going on?

Thanks in advance
Or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a mapping between files in the local file system (e.g. index.html) and resources accessible by URL.  I don't know what tool you are using to create your web app, but I know that in Eclipse all files uses by the web app are stored within the WebContent directory.  It's just the convention it uses.  When the app is deployed to the web server this directory is the root directory within the app context path.

Comment: Ok, i thought so to, so i tried using this url also: http://www.ctdm.org:8080/WebCT/index.html but I still get the 404 error

Comment: You're missing "www" at the beginning?  index.html is in the WebContent folder right?  You may need to redeploy your project to Web server so that index.html is included in the app.

Comment: Are you developing in Eclipse?

Comment: i'm not developing in eclipse, there is 'www' at the beginning, index.html is in the WebContent folder and what do you mean redeploy my project to the Web server? i have access to the server, i just put the relevant files in the right places (i hope so)

Comment: You can use the Tomcat manager app to reload WebCT.  http://www.ctdm.org:8080/manager  

Try it with index.html within the WebCT directory too.